# Induced surjective group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

If $A * \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow B * \mathbb{Z} $ is a surjective group homomorphism then does this induce a surjective group homomorphism $A \rightarrow B $?

Comment: What is $*$? Do you mean $A\times \mathbb Z$ or do you really mean the free product of the groups?

Comment: I mean free product.

Comment: Not in any obvious way.  For example, consider the case where $A=B=\mathbb{Z}$, and the given homomorphism switches the two factors.

Comment: That raises the more general question of whether $A*C \cong B*C$ implies $A \cong B$.